# How To Generate An SQL Insert Query From A List Of Values?

Tags: php, sql

I have a long list of values and i want to insert them into the database using SQL Query, but writing the statement is taking too long. Is there any way in php, that will give me a ready to use INSERT query from the list of values provided?

I am hereby providing my (incomplete)SQL Query :

```
INSERT INTO `aichiwj2_reesk`.`me_skills` 
(`id`, `skill_name`, `skill_type`, `timestamp`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, 'Able To Listen', 'it', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
(NULL, 'Accept Feedback', 'it', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`
```

.....and this continues....

Hereby i am providing the list of values (I am using `<li>` to view the values one after the other or else, it was viewing all together):

Able to Listen

Accept Feedback

Adaptable

Artistic Sense

Assertive

Attentive

Business Storytelling

Business Trend Awareness

Collaborating

Communication

Competitive

Confidant

Conflict Resolution

Cooperative

Courteous

Crisis Management

Critical Observer

Critical Thinker

Customer Service

Deal Making

Deal with Difficult Situations

Deal with Office Politics

Deals with Difficult People

Decision Making

Dedicated

Delegation

Dependable

Design Sense

Desire to Learn

Disability Awareness

Dispute Resolution

Diversity Awareness

Answer (score 1):

Place your list of skills inside an array, iterate over the array and echo the SQL string to the browser. It's not fancy, but get the job done.

I am really rusty in PHP, so I'll not be able to paste a full solution. Something like this may work, but I haven't been able to test it since I don't have a machine with PHP right now.

```
$array = ("Skill1", "Skill2", "Skill3");
$queries_string = "INSERT INTO `aichiwj2_reesk`.`me_skills` (`id`, `skill_name`, `skill_type`, `timestamp`) VALUES ";
for ($i = 0; $i < len($array); $i++)
    $queries_string .= "(NULL, '"+$array[$i]+"', 'it', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), ";
echo $queries_string
```

After it prints on the screen you should replace the sinal space and comma with ;

Sorry I can't help anymore than that right now.

Comment: Well, actually i am an amateur in php. Don't know the concept of arrays yet. Would be great if you can write the code for atleast 5 values.

Comment: Try the code I just added. Don't remember the PHP substring function, but you can manually replace the last space and comma with ; after PHP prints on the screen.

Comment: Sorry! It says - Line : 2,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: Try replacing [ and ] for parentesis on line 2. Like this: ["Skill1", "Skill2", "Skill3"];

Comment: Error Again: Line : 2,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Not sure from which version that syntax is supported. You can check how to create an array here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I am using PHP 5.2.17 & the error showing on server is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /***********/query.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

I have used this trick in the past, put your values in EXCEL and then `CONCAT()` a string together to get your `INSERT` statements.

I.e.
"INSERT INTO `aichiwj2_reesk`.`me_skills` 
(`id`, `skill_name`, `skill_type`, `timestamp`) 
VALUES ("+Col1+......

And then paste your `INSERT` statements into your QUERY EDITOR and `RUN` not the most technical way to do it, but it gets the job done

Comment: Any other way you know ? Excel is not something i am familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$skills=array("Able to Listen","Accept Feedback","Adaptable",
              "Artistic Sense","Assertive","Attentive","Business Storytelling",
              "Business Trend Awareness","Collaborating","Communication",
              "Competitive","Confidant","Conflict Resolution","Cooperative",
              "Courteous","Crisis Management","Critical Observer",
              "Critical Thinker","Customer Service",
              "Deal Making","Deal with Difficult Situations",
              "Deal with Office Politics",
              "Deals with Difficult People","Decision Making","Dedicated",
              "Delegation","Dependable","Design Sense","Desire to Learn",
              "Disability Awareness","Dispute Resolution",
              "Diversity Awareness");
foreach ($skills as $val) {
    mysql_query("insert into aichiwj2_reesk (skill_name, skill_type, timestamp) values ('$val', 'it', 'CURRENT_TIME')");
}
```

For timestamp you can take time in var from above the loop and insert into query replacing CURRENT_TIME. If you want to take date then you can also take date.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'to' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /*******/query.php on line 10

Comment: I have working please check you have placed write code. And check your query which you are passing is correct with braces and take care about quotations.